# serialization process of non serializable injected bean with keyword 'transient'

Tags: java, serialization, cdi

I have a problem around serialization in java.

Here is a test case class `TestLoggerBean`:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.io.Serializable;


public final class TestLoggerBean implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    protected transient Log logger;

    @Inject
    protected Log logger2;

    public void showMessage() {
        this.logger.info( "Logger 1" );
    }

    public void showMessage2() {
        this.logger2.info( "Logger 2" );
    }
}
```

TestClass:

```
public class TestClass implements Serializable {
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;


    @Inject
    private TestLoggerBean testLoggerBean;

    public void testSerial() {

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutput out = null;

        byte[] yourBytes = null;
        try {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            out.writeObject( this.testLoggerBean );
            out.flush();
            yourBytes = bos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // ignore close exception
        } finally {
            try {
                bos.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // ignore close exception
            }
        }

        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(yourBytes);
        ObjectInput in = null;
        TestLoggerBean o = null;
        try {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            o = (TestLoggerBean) in.readObject();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // ignore close exception
        } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // ignore close exception
        }

        o.showMessage2();

        o.showMessage();
    }
}
```

See screenshot:

[Screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmRUE.png)

**Up**: Object before serialization;

**Down**: Object after serialization

We can see that the transient field is `null` (up).
The non transient field seems to has re-inject the object after the serialization. For my application the behavior of the non transient field works fine. See example function `showMessage2`. The transient field will cause a `NullPointerException` in method `showMessage()`.

Now I have following problem. In my project the serialization of objects is very import and I'm pleased with every features which helps to detect serialization issues. My IDE (Intellij) shows for the non transient field:
[Screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kLTJ.png). Based on my test result I cant use the keyword 'transient', my application wont work. Without the keyword 'transient' the application works, but I can't use the code analysis feature.

My question. Did I miss something general in my test case? What is the best way to deal with these situation? Both option in the test cast are not really usable for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the loggers static final, and avoid injecting the logger with the annotation [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806550/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-a-logger-in-a-serializable-java-class)

Comment: thanks for u answer, but these is not usable for me. The logger is an example. We have oder injections with a similar behavior.

Comment: i decided to make this for logger like you described. So i don't have these issue for the logs. Thanx for hint

Answer (score 0):

The `transient` keyword, in combination with CDI, means that the injection into such field will only be done while first instantiating such object. E.g. when first creating it.

If, any time after that, the object needs to be seriliazed/deseriliazed `transient` field **will not be re-injected** (while other field would be - that's what you observer with the other field).

If you destroy such bean and re-instantiate it (e.g. session bean which expires) then the `transient` field will be injected again up until first serialization.

Comment: thanks for u answer. This confirmed my thoughts, but for me it is still not clear how i should handle these situation.

Comment: @SimonA am not really sure what is the problem in your case. The fact that the logger is not serializable? Then I suggest exploring why it isn't serializable. Maybe the IDE is giving you a **false positive** and it would work. And if nothing else, i suppose you could create a serializable wrapper class for those loggers which you will then inject. BTW in your screenshot, the *non*-transient field was re-injected, even though it was the same type of logger; so why do you need it transient?

Comment: I do not need the transient. But i need the IDE check for the real problematic serialization issues. And it's seems that this check works fine. The log is not serializable.
I'm not sure if even my general using of the logger is not already a bad variant and how should i general handle injection of non serializable objects in a serializable one.